# Who's triggering onLocationChanged in LocationManager in Android?

Tags: android, geolocation, gps, location

I was looking for this answer in previous posts about Android's Location Provider but I couldn't find the answer. How is onLocationChanged triggered and what is the process since the GPS daemon/library fixes a location until it reaches the LocationManager? Is it directly triggered by the Gps daemon or does it go first somewhere in the Android Java Framework?

Many thanks

N

Comment: this is a good question. I'm looking at the source code and trying to figure out exactly where the location is coming from. I'm lost in a sea of interfaces, though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been looking around the code and this is what i have thus far:

requestLocationUpdates registers the onLocationChangeListener.
This in turn [gets stored](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/location/LocationManager.java#LocationManager._requestLocationUpdates%28java.lang.String,android.location.Criteria,long,float,boolean,android.location.LocationListener,android.os.Looper%29) as a key in a hashmap with a value of a ListenerTransport.

The ListenerTransport has a [private variable](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/location/LocationManager.java#LocationManager.ListenerTransport.%3Cinit%3E%28android.location.LocationListener%2Candroid.os.Looper%29) which is the listener in question. The ListenerTransport just seems to be a class that recieves a message, which [calls the onLocationChange method](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.3.4_r1/android/location/LocationManager.java#LocationManager.ListenerTransport._handleMessage%28android.os.Message%29) of the listener.

This is where i'm lost:
The ListenerTransport extends `ILocationListener.Stubs` which extends Binder. Hence, its a type of RPC call. But where does the call go?

I've noticed in `ILocationListener.Proxy` in `requestLocationUpdates()`, theres a call to `IBinder.transact(Stub.TRANSACTION_requestLocationUpdates,...)`. It's to be seen where this goes and what happens...

Comment: Thanks! This is really helpful, so basically the daemon/library communicates directly with GpsLocationProvider through IBinder using the reportLocation method

Comment: that's how it seems. Although i wouldn't say with certainty that it's through the reportLocation method. More likely it's through a message (eventually) caught by the handler in the Listener Transport.
But what i can't figure out is what sends this message to begin with..

Answer (score 1):

Check here:[More about Location in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationManager.html#requestLocationUpdates%28long,%20float,%20android.location.Criteria,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)

and [Location Listener in Android](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html)

This will help you!

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response but this is not what I'm looking for. This is basically how this works from the apps perspective... I want to see where and how the GPS library/daemon reports new location updates to GpsLocationProvider via using reportLocation(...).